# How to use custom BasicAuthenticationFilter with default configuration?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using spring security 5.8.7

One of my filter chains looks like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain remotingFilterChain( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    return http
            .securityMatcher( "/remoting/**" )
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
            .httpBasic()
                    .and()
            .anonymous()
                    .and()
            .x509()
                    .subjectPrincipalRegex( "CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)" )
                    .and()
            .csrf()
                    .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                    .disable()
            .build();
}
```

Now I want to customize the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` by overriding the two methods

```
@Override
protected String getCredentialsCharset( HttpServletRequest httpRequest ) {
    // switch charset for some conditions
}

@Override
protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
    // increase login failure count
}
```

It looks like this should be done by implementing

```
class MyBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    ...
}
```

and calling

```
            .addFilterAt( new MyBasicAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class )
```

But at the same time I don't want to miss the default configuration provided by the call of `http.httpBasic()`. But `HttpBasicConfigurer` is final, so I cannot extend it and override the method `configure()` where the call `new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, this.authenticationEntryPoint);` is made.

Another approach would be to use

```
            .httpBasic()
                    .withObjectPostProcessor( myPostProcessor )
                    .and()
```

and enhancing the originally created `BasicAuthenticationFilter` with the two overridden methods. But `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is not an interface, so I can't make use of the java `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` pattern.

Any idea, how I can use a customized `BasicAuthenticationFilter` with a simple and default configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain remotingFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain = http
                .securityMatcher("/remoting/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .anonymous(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .x509(c -> c.subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)"))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .build();
        List<Filter> filters = filterChain.getFilters();
        for (int i = 0; i < filters.size(); i++) {
            Filter filter = filters.get(i);
            if(filter instanceof BasicAuthenticationFilter){
                filters.remove(i);
                filters.add(i,new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class), (BasicAuthenticationFilter) filter));
                break;
            }
        }
        return filterChain;
    }

    static class CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

        public CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,BasicAuthenticationFilter filter) {
            super(authenticationManager);
            Field authenticationEntryPoint = ReflectionUtils.findField(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class, "authenticationEntryPoint");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(authenticationEntryPoint);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(authenticationEntryPoint,this,ReflectionUtils.getField(authenticationEntryPoint, filter));

            Field securityContextHolderStrategy = ReflectionUtils.findField(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class, "securityContextHolderStrategy");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(securityContextHolderStrategy);
            setSecurityContextHolderStrategy((SecurityContextHolderStrategy) ReflectionUtils.getField(securityContextHolderStrategy, filter));

            Field rememberMeServices = ReflectionUtils.findField(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class, "rememberMeServices");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(rememberMeServices);
            setRememberMeServices((RememberMeServices) ReflectionUtils.getField(rememberMeServices, filter));

            Field authenticationConverter = ReflectionUtils.findField(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class, "authenticationConverter");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(authenticationConverter);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(authenticationConverter,this,ReflectionUtils.getField(authenticationConverter, filter));

            Field securityContextRepository = ReflectionUtils.findField(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class, "securityContextRepository");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(securityContextRepository);
            setSecurityContextRepository((SecurityContextRepository) ReflectionUtils.getField(securityContextRepository, filter));
        }

        @Override
        protected String getCredentialsCharset( HttpServletRequest httpRequest ) {
            // switch charset for some conditions
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                    AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
            // increase login failure count
        }
    }
```